# PHP variables not transferring to fwrite

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am having an issue getting additional variables to be processed through fwrite. When include only the $roll variable, it writes properly.  What's happening is the random number from the $roll goes into chat.txt, but when adding $quantity and $dice, then nothing displays (not even the $roll). What I would like to have happen, is the user selects the quantity of dice, the dice type, and then roll. The text from roll should then write to chat.txt. Again, the problem is only occurring when adding the $quantity and $dice variables. Please forgive my newbyness.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))//on submit
    {
        $roll = $_POST['roll'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $dice = $_POST['dice'];
        $nickname = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['nickname']));
        fwrite(fopen('chat.txt', 'a'), "<span>". $nickname . " :</span>" . $$roll = str_replace("\n", " ", $quantity, $dice, $roll) . "\n");
        fclose($file); 
        print_r(error_get_last());
    }
?>

<form action="" id="rollBox" name="rollBox" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="roll" id="demo">
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="10">
    <select name="dice">
        <option value="d4">d4</option>
        <option value="d6">d6</option>
        <option value="d8">d8</option>
        <option value="d10">d10</option>
        <option value="d12">d12</option>
        <option value="d20">d20</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" >Roll</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#rollBox').submit(function(e) {
var x=document.getElementById("demo")
x.value=Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
e.preventDefault();
var obj = $(this), // (*) references the current object/form each time
                        url = obj.attr('action'),
                        method = obj.attr('method'),
                        data = {};
                        obj.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
                        var obj = $(this),
                            name = obj.attr('name'),
                            value = obj.val();
                        data[name] = value;
                    });
$.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: method,
                        data: data,
                        success: function(response2) {}
                        });
                        return false; 
});
});

</script>

<p id="name-area"></p>
<div id="chatWrap"><div id="chat-area"></div></div>

<form id="send-message-area">
    <p>Your message: </p>
    <textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '200' ></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str_replace("\n", " ", $quantity, $dice, $roll)
```

You are passing extra arguments to the `str_replace` functions. You probably want to pass last three as one, so you have to quote them:

```
str_replace("\n", " ", "$quantity, $dice, $roll")
```

Comment: Doing this made the entire chatWrap div disappear

Comment: Have you checked your file to see if it was written properly? Depending on the content of these variables, you may have to escape it before displaying, to avoid malformed HTML

Comment: Mostly the issue was regarding the way I passed the extra arguments. Thank you @dev-null-dweller

Answer (score 2):

You have an error here:

```
$$roll = str_replace("\n", " ", $quantity, $dice, $roll)
```

Remove one **$**

Also, look at the str_replace declaration:

```
mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```

You have too much arguments.

Comment: str_replace() can have 4 parameters atmost, you have 5 check that one.

Comment: Sorry I am still pretty new with this. I appreciate the feedback, but could you maybe be a little more specific?

Comment: Check answer from @MillaresRoo

Comment: @Aldentec What are you trying to achieve with this statement? `$roll = str_replace("\n", " ", $quantity, $dice, $roll)`

Comment: Well I believed it would allow me to fwrite the variables to the chat.txt. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: No, str_replace only replaces all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string. In your case, looks like you are trying to replace "\n" with " " in $quantity, $dice and $roll. It's correct?

Comment: no, it will end up with the following Warning: str_replace() expects at most 4 parameters, 5 given on line [line num]

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm only trying to know what he wanted to do. :)

Comment: Oh @MillaresRoo comment was for Aldentec, somehow it came just after you replied, my apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

`$file` is never defined. Separate your lines out like this:

```
$file = fopen('chat.txt', 'a');
fwrite($file, "<span>". $nickname . " :</span>" . $$roll = str_replace("\n", " ", $quantity, $dice, $roll) . "\n");
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up, but it still did not resolve the issue of $quantity and $dice not being written

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The issue was resolved with a combination of answers from you guys. Thanks for the help everyone. By the way the new code is as follows:

```
<div id="pageWrap">

<div id="expander"> Expand</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))//on submit
{
    $roll = $_POST['roll'];
    $quantity= $_POST['quantity'];
    $dice = $_POST['dice'];
    $nickname = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['nickname']));
    $file = fopen('chat.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($file, "<span>". $nickname . " :</span>" . $roll = str_replace("\n", " ", "    <em> Rolls </em>$quantity $dice <em>for</em> $roll") . "\n");
    fclose($file);
}
?>

<form action="" id="rollBox" name="rollBox" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="roll" id="demo">
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="10">
    <select name="dice">
        <option value="d4">d4</option>
        <option value="d6">d6</option>
        <option value="d8">d8</option>
        <option value="d10">d10</option>
        <option value="d12">d12</option>
        <option value="d20">d20</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" >Roll</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#rollBox').submit(function(e) {
var x=document.getElementById("demo")
x.value=Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
e.preventDefault();
var obj = $(this), // (*) references the current object/form each time
                        url = obj.attr('action'),
                        method = obj.attr('method'),
                        data = {};
                        obj.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
                        var obj = $(this),
                            name = obj.attr('name'),
                            value = obj.val();
                        data[name] = value;
                    });
$.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: method,
                        data: data,
                        success: function(response2) {}
                        });
                        return false; 
});
});

</script>
</form>
<p id="name-area"></p>
<div id="chatWrap"><div id="chat-area"></div></div>

<form id="send-message-area">
    <p>Your message: </p>
    <textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '200' ></textarea>
</form>

</div>
```